# Under what conditions $f$ and $g$ are open maps?

Tags: general-topology

Let the composition of two arbitrary function $f$ and $g$ be an open function. Under what conditions $f$ and $g$ are open maps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f:X\to Y$ and $g:Y\to Z$ be functions between topological spaces and let $h$ denote the composition of $f$ and $g$. Assume that $h$ is open. Then you have

- If $g$ is injective and continuous, then for an open subset $U$ of $X$
  we have $f(U)=g^{-1}(h(U)),$ so $f$ is open.
- If $f$ is surjective and continuous, then for an open subset $V$ of $Y$
  we have $g(V)=h(f^{-1}(V)),$ so $g$ is open.

In general, we have $h(f^{-1}(V))=g(V\cap f(X))$ for a set $V\subseteq Y.$