# Is there a counter example?

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples

Is this true?
If $f$ and $g $ are continuous functions , and if $f\circ g$ is closed(open) , neither $g$ nor $f$ is necessarily closed(open)?

Comment: What do you mean by closed/open function?

Comment: @StefanSmith Hm.. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_and_closed_maps

Answer (score 1):

Let $f:I\hookrightarrow \Bbb R$ be the inclusion of the unit interval into the real line, and let $g:\Bbb R \twoheadrightarrow I$ be the retraction sending $(-\infty,0]$ to $\{0\}$ and $[1,\infty)$ to $\{1\}$. Then $gf$ is a homeomorphism $I\approx I$, thus open, but neither $f$ nor $g$ are open.

- $f$ maps the open $I$ to the non-open $I.$
- $g$ maps the open $(-2,-1)$ to the non-open $\{0\}.$

However, if $gf$ is open, $g$ and $f$ are continuous, and ...

- ... if $g$ is injective, then $f$ must be open.
- ... if $f$ is surjective, then $g$ must be open.

For an explanation see [Under what conditions $f$ and $g$ are open maps?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/496645/under-what-conditions-f-and-g-are-open-maps/496657#496657)